# Changing classes via jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have looked this up, and feel that I am very close to figuring it out, but haven't been able to get it to work.

```
$(function() {

    // Set up variables
    var $el, $parentWrap, $otherWrap, 
        $allTitles = $("dt").css({
            padding: 5, // setting the padding here prevents a weird situation, where it would start animating at 0 padding instead of 5
            "cursor": "pointer" // make it seem clickable
        }),
        $allCells = $("dd").css({
            position: "relative",
            top: -1,
            left: 0,
            display: "none" // info cells are just kicked off the page with CSS (for accessibility)
        });

    // clicking image of inactive column just opens column, doesn't go to link   
    $("#page-wrap").delegate("a.image","click", function(e) { 

        if ( !$(this).parent().hasClass("curCol") ) {         
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $(this).next().find('dt:first').click(); 
        } 

    });

    // clicking on titles does stuff
    $("#page-wrap").delegate("dt", "click", function() {

        // cache this, as always, is good form
        $el = $(this);

        // if this is already the active cell, don't do anything
        if (!$el.hasClass("current")) {

            $parentWrap = $el.parent().parent();
            $otherWraps = $(".info-col").not($parentWrap);

            // remove current cell from selection of all cells
            $allTitles = $("dt").not(this);

            // close all info cells
            $allCells.slideUp();

            // return all titles (except current one) to normal size
            $allTitles.animate({
                paddingTop: 5,
                paddingRight: 5,
                paddingBottom: 5,
                paddingLeft: 5

            });

            // animate current title to larger size            
            $el.animate({
                paddingTop: 10,
                paddingRight: 5,
                paddingBottom: 0,
                paddingLeft: 10
            }).next().slideDown();

            // make the current column the large size
            $parentWrap.animate({
                width: 160,
                opacity: 1
            }).addClass("curCol");


        var theParent = $(this).parent().prev();

            console.log($(this));

            var theClass = theParent.attr("class");

            var theAttribute = $(this).parent().prev().attr("data-type","this");

            theAttribute.attr("class","solo"+theClass); */

            $parentWrap.children().children().animate({
                "height" : "518",
                "width" : "145",
                "opacity": "1.0"
            });

            // make other columns the small size
            $otherWraps.animate({
                width: 106,
                opacity: 0.8
            }).removeClass("curCol");   


            $otherWraps.children().children().animate({
                "height" : "70",
                "width" : "96",
                "opacity" : "0.5"
            });

        $otherWraps.children().attr("class").replace("solo","");        

            // make sure the correct column is current
            $allTitles.removeClass("current");
            $el.addClass("current");  

        }

    });

    $("#starter").trigger("click");

});
```

I am using classes to change out the background image in this modification to infogrid.js. I am able to change the classes from the original name of the person, to their name+"solo", and that works fine.
The problem is stripping out the "solo" once that  is no longer the selected one. 
On line # 97 (if you open it in your code editor), I am trying to revert the class of each  to the original class(the name of each person-"omni").
I have spent about 3 hours on this, but haven't been able to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. 
Cheers,
Marc.

Comment: Did you know there's a `addClass` and `removeClass` function in jquery?

Comment: cfr remark from treetree , from there it's very easy to select elements with both classes or the ones with only the original class

Comment: ^ My guess according to the question is no

Comment: @Bartdude What does cfr stand for?

Comment: @TreeTree : cfr = abbreviation for latin "confere" (should have put a dot at the end) = commonly used (at least in French) to mean "refer to"

Comment: I am aware of .addClass and .removeClass, but I wasn't wanting to remove the entire class, just the prefix "solo" that I had added earlier, while leaving the original, div-specific class (the person's name) that was in the div.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Line 97 is the problem line for you and this is what's happening there:

```
$otherWraps.children().attr("class").replace("solo","");
```

When you use the `attr` function and you omit the second parameter, then you're calling the `get` version of that function. So you're retrieving the class name then modifying it, but not reassigning it back to the children.

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

What you probably want is:

```
$otherWraps.children ().each (function () {
    var className = $(this).attr ('class');
    $(this).attr ('class', className.replace ('solo', ''));
});
```

Here you're giving it a second parameter which is the `set` version of the function.

I expanded it to the above form because I don't know what would happen if you tried:

`$otherWraps.children().attr("class", $otherWraps.children().attr("class").replace("solo",""));`

Won't even fit on one line!